# Mistaking something for something

Tags: idiom

How do I phrase "mistaking something for something" idiomatically in Latin?
There is always a way around if one wants to explain (eg. "I mistook the cat for a dog" > *Felem canem esse falso putabam*), but I imagine there would be a Latin idiom for this purpose.
I couldn't find a Latin translation of The Man Who Mistook His Wife for a Hat, and I'm out of ideas how to look for an idiom like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your examples, I suggest :

*Felem credidi canem esse*, in which the mistake is implicit, or

*Homo qui coniugem pro petaso finxit*, 'the man who imagined that his wife was a hat'.